# How to display tabs after login and change tabs without making root on another page in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a requirement where in I need to design Ionic pages in Ionic 3 as per attached designs I have shared.

Basically what I need is after login display Work Orders screen where in I have few tabs. The tabs are not in Menu, just at the bottom. Here I know I can tap on a tab item and make it a root page.

But I am stuck at the second part where after tapping on a list item a new page need to be displayed. This page will also have few tabs as shown. Now here the Content section needs to be replaced with the Tab.

If I tap on Tab1 then tab 1 content needs to be replaced on center Content section and similarly on tab2 and tab3. Similarly Orders, Cust and Cart should also replace Content section

One way is to use *ngIf directive for all three tabs and 3 upper tabs with their selectors.

```
<tab1 *ngIf="isShownTab1"></tab1>
<tab2 *ngIf="isShownTab2"></tab2>
<tab3 *ngIf="isShownTab3"></tab3>
.....
```

Controlling the values of variables `isShownTab1` etc from Component.

But is this the right way of doing it. What would be the best approach for this.
Since if there are many horizontal scrollable tabs say 20-30. What should be the way to do?

Please help!

[image: After login]
[image: Tapping on order item from previous screen]

Comment: Have you tried ionic `Segment`? This may be more suitable for your requirements. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/

Comment: @Huiting thanks it worked.